# For each row: search for the previous row at least 20 seconds before

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, time, iteration

##### Problem:

For each row of a DataFrame, I want to find the nearest prior row where the `'Datetime'` value is **at least** 20 seconds before the current `'Datetime'` value.

For example: if the previous `'Datetime'` (at index `i-1`) is at least 20s earlier than the current one - it will be chosen. Otherwise (e.g. only 5 seconds earlier), move to `i-2` and see if *it* is at least 20s earlier. Repeat until the condition is met, or no such row has been found.

The expected result is a concatenation of the original `df` and the rows that were found. When no matching row at or more than 20 s before the current `Datetime` has been found, then the new columns are null (`NaT` or `NaN`, depending on the type).

##### Example data

```py
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'Datetime': pd.to_datetime([
        f'2016-05-15 08:{M_S}+06:00'
        for M_S in ['36:21', '36:41', '36:50', '37:10', '37:19', '37:39']]),
    'A': [21, 43, 54, 2, 54, 67],
    'B': [3, 3, 45, 23, 8, 6],
})
```

##### Example result:

```py
>>> res
  Datetime                   A   B  Datetime_nearest           A_nearest  B_nearest
0 2016-05-15 08:36:21+06:00  21   3                       NaT   NaN        NaN     
1 2016-05-15 08:36:41+06:00  43   3 2016-05-15 08:36:21+06:00  21.0        3.0     
2 2016-05-15 08:36:50+06:00  54  45 2016-05-15 08:36:21+06:00  21.0        3.0     
3 2016-05-15 08:37:10+06:00   2  23 2016-05-15 08:36:50+06:00  54.0       45.0     
4 2016-05-15 08:37:19+06:00  54   8 2016-05-15 08:36:50+06:00  54.0       45.0     
5 2016-05-15 08:37:39+06:00  67   6 2016-05-15 08:37:19+06:00  54.0        8.0
```

The last three columns are the newly created columns, and the first three columns are the original dataset.

Comment: I forgot to put NaN to A_nearest and B_nearest (index 0).

Comment: Please [do not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551) and provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), including a small example input data **and the corresponding expected result**.

Answer (score 1):

### Two vectorized solutions

**Note**: we assume that the rows are sorted by `Datetime`. If that is not the case, then sort them first (`O[n log n]`).

For 10,000 rows:

1. 3.3 ms, using Numpy's `searchsorted`.
2. 401 ms, using a `rolling` window of 20s, left-open.

#### 1. Using `np.searchsorted`

We use [`np.searchsorted`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.searchsorted.html) to find in one call the indices of all matching rows:

```py
import numpy as np

s = df['Datetime']
z  = np.searchsorted(s, s - (pd.Timedelta(min_dt) - pd.Timedelta('1ns'))) - 1
```

E.g., for the OP's data, these indices are:

```
>>> z
array([-1,  0,  0,  2,  2,  4])
```

I.e.: `z[0] == -1`: no matching row; `z[1] == 0`: row 0 (08:36:21) is the nearest that is 20s or more before row 1 (08:36:41). `z[2] == 0`: row 0 is the nearest match for row 2 (row 1 is too close). Etc.

**Why subtracting 1?** We use `np.searchsorted` to select the first row in the *exclusion zone* (i.e., too close); then we subtract 1 to get the correct row (the first one at least 20s before).

**Why `- 1ns`?** This is to make the search window left-open. A row at exactly 20s before the current one will *not* be in the exclusion zone, and thus will end up being the one selected as the match.

We then use `z` to select the matching rows (or nulls) and concatenate into the result. Putting it all in a function:

```py
def select_np(df, min_dt='20s'):
    newcols = [f'{k}_nearest' for k in df.columns]
    s = df['Datetime']
    z = np.searchsorted(s, s - (pd.Timedelta(min_dt) - pd.Timedelta('1ns'))) - 1
    return pd.concat([
        df,
        df.iloc[z].set_axis(newcols, axis=1).reset_index(drop=True).where(pd.Series(z >= 0))
    ], axis=1)
```

**On the OP's example**

```py
>>> select_np(df[['Datetime', 'A', 'B']])
  Datetime                   A   B  Datetime_nearest           A_nearest  B_nearest
0 2016-05-15 08:36:21+06:00  21   3                       NaT   NaN        NaN     
1 2016-05-15 08:36:41+06:00  43   3 2016-05-15 08:36:21+06:00  21.0        3.0     
2 2016-05-15 08:36:50+06:00  54  45 2016-05-15 08:36:21+06:00  21.0        3.0     
3 2016-05-15 08:37:10+06:00   2  23 2016-05-15 08:36:50+06:00  54.0       45.0     
4 2016-05-15 08:37:19+06:00  54   8 2016-05-15 08:36:50+06:00  54.0       45.0     
5 2016-05-15 08:37:39+06:00  67   6 2016-05-15 08:37:19+06:00  54.0        8.0
```

#### 2. Using a rolling window (pure Pandas)

This was our original solution and uses pandas [`rolling`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.rolling.html) with a `Timedelta(20s)` window size, left-open. It is still more optimized than a naive (`O[n^2]`) search, but is roughly 100x slower than `select_np()`, as `pandas` uses explicit loops in Python to find the window bounds for `.rolling()`: see [`get_window_bounds()`](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/62a69beddbedde349891378992c902c0b9341a9f/pandas/core/indexers/objects.py#L148). There is also some overhead due to having to make sub-frames, applying a function or aggregate, etc.

```py
def select_pd(df, min_dt='20s'):
    newcols = [f'{k}_nearest' for k in df.columns]
    z = (
        df.assign(rownum=range(len(df)))
        .rolling(pd.Timedelta(min_dt), on='Datetime', closed='right')['rownum']
        .apply(min).astype(int) - 1
    )
    return pd.concat([
        df,
        df.iloc[z].set_axis(newcols, axis=1).reset_index(drop=True).where(z >= 0)
    ], axis=1)
```

#### 3. Testing

First, we write an arbitrary-size test data generator:

```py
def gen(n):
    return pd.DataFrame({
        'Datetime': pd.Timestamp('2020') +\
            np.random.randint(0, 30, n).cumsum() * pd.Timedelta('1s'),
        'A': np.random.randint(0, 100, n),
        'B': np.random.randint(0, 100, n),
    })
```

**Example**

```py
np.random.seed(0)
tdf = gen(10)

>>> select_np(tdf)
  Datetime             A   B  Datetime_nearest     A_nearest  B_nearest
0 2020-01-01 00:00:12  21  87                 NaT   NaN        NaN     
1 2020-01-01 00:00:27  36  46                 NaT   NaN        NaN     
2 2020-01-01 00:00:48  87  88 2020-01-01 00:00:27  36.0       46.0     
3 2020-01-01 00:00:48  70  81 2020-01-01 00:00:27  36.0       46.0     
4 2020-01-01 00:00:51  88  37 2020-01-01 00:00:27  36.0       46.0     
5 2020-01-01 00:01:18  88  25 2020-01-01 00:00:51  88.0       37.0     
6 2020-01-01 00:01:21  12  77 2020-01-01 00:00:51  88.0       37.0     
7 2020-01-01 00:01:28  58  72 2020-01-01 00:00:51  88.0       37.0     
8 2020-01-01 00:01:37  65   9 2020-01-01 00:00:51  88.0       37.0     
9 2020-01-01 00:01:56  39  20 2020-01-01 00:01:28  58.0       72.0
```

**Speed**

```py
tdf = gen(10_000)

% timeit select_np(tdf)
3.31 ms ± 6.79 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)

%timeit select_pd(df)
401 ms ± 1.66 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

>>> select_np(df).equals(select_pd(df))
True
```

**Scale sweep**

We can now compare speed over a range of sizes, using the excellent [`perfplot`](https://pypi.org/project/perfplot/0.2.1/) package:

```py
import perfplot

perfplot.plot(
    setup=gen,
    kernels=[select_np, select_pd],
    n_range=[2**k for k in range(4, 16)],
    equality_check=lambda a, b: a.equals(b),
)
```

[image]

**Focusing on `select_np`**:

```py
perfplot.plot(
    setup=gen,
    kernels=[select_np],
    n_range=[2**k for k in range(4, 24)],
)
```

[image]

Comment: Great answer! Thanks! Learned a lot. (even though there are no other upvotes)

Answer (score 0):

The following solution is memory-efficient but it is not the fastest one (because it uses iteration over rows).

The fully vectorized version (that I could think of on my own) would be faster but it would use `O(n^2)` memory.

##### Example dataframe:

```py
timestamps = [pd.Timestamp('2016-01-01 00:00:00'),
              pd.Timestamp('2016-01-01 00:00:19'),
              pd.Timestamp('2016-01-01 00:00:20'),
              pd.Timestamp('2016-01-01 00:00:21'),
              pd.Timestamp('2016-01-01 00:00:50')]
df = pd.DataFrame({'Datetime': timestamps,
                   'A': np.arange(10, 15),
                   'B': np.arange(20, 25)})
```

|  | Datetime | A | B |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 2016-01-01 00:00:00 | 10 | 20 |
| 1 | 2016-01-01 00:00:19 | 11 | 21 |
| 2 | 2016-01-01 00:00:20 | 12 | 22 |
| 3 | 2016-01-01 00:00:21 | 13 | 23 |
| 4 | 2016-01-01 00:00:50 | 14 | 24 |

### Solution:

```py
times = df['Datetime'].to_numpy()  # it's convenient to have it as an `ndarray`
shifted_times = times - pd.Timedelta(20, unit='s')
```

- `useful` is a list of "useful" indices of `df` - i.e. where the appended values will NOT be `nan`:

```py
useful = np.nonzero(shifted_times >= times[0])[0]
# useful == [2, 3, 4]
```

- Truncate `shifted_times` from the beginning - to iterate through useful elements only:

```py
if len(useful) == 0:
    # all new columns will be `nan`s
    first_i = 0  # this value will never actually be used
    useful_shifted_times = np.array([], dtype=shifted_times.dtype)
else:
    first_i = useful[0]  # first_i == 2
    useful_shifted_times = shifted_times[first_i : ]
```

- Find the corresponding index positions of `df` for each "useful" value.

  (these index positions are essentially the indices of `times`
  that are selected for each element of `useful_shifted_times`):

```py
selected_indices = []

# Iterate through `useful_shifted_times` one by one:
# (`i` starts at `first_i`)
for i, shifted_time in enumerate(useful_shifted_times, first_i):
    selected_index = np.nonzero(times[: i] <= shifted_time)[0][-1]
    selected_indices.append(selected_index)

# selected_indices == [0, 0, 3]
```

- Selected rows:

```py
df_nearest = df.iloc[selected_indices].add_suffix('_nearest')
```

|  | Datetime_nearest | A_nearest | B_nearest |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 2016-01-01 00:00:00 | 10 | 20 |
| 0 | 2016-01-01 00:00:00 | 10 | 20 |
| 3 | 2016-01-01 00:00:21 | 13 | 23 |

- Replace indices of `df_nearest` to match those of the corresponding  rows of `df`.

  (basically, that is the last `len(selected_indices)` indices):

```py
df_nearest.index = df.index[len(df) - len(selected_indices) : ]
```

|  | Datetime_nearest | A_nearest | B_nearest |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | 2016-01-01 00:00:00 | 10 | 20 |
| 3 | 2016-01-01 00:00:00 | 10 | 20 |
| 4 | 2016-01-01 00:00:21 | 13 | 23 |

- Append the selected rows to the original dataframe to get **the final result**:

```py
new_df = df.join(df_nearest)
```

|  | Datetime | A | B | Datetime_nearest | A_nearest | B_nearest |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 2016-01-01 00:00:00 | 10 | 20 | NaT | nan | nan |
| 1 | 2016-01-01 00:00:19 | 11 | 21 | NaT | nan | nan |
| 2 | 2016-01-01 00:00:20 | 12 | 22 | 2016-01-01 00:00:00 | 10 | 20 |
| 3 | 2016-01-01 00:00:21 | 13 | 23 | 2016-01-01 00:00:00 | 10 | 20 |
| 4 | 2016-01-01 00:00:50 | 14 | 24 | 2016-01-01 00:00:21 | 13 | 23 |

---

Note: [`NaT`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/missing_data.html) stands for 'Not a Time'. It is the equivalent of `nan` for time values.

Note: it also works as expected even if all the last `'Datetime'` `- 20 sec` is before the very first `'Datetime'` --> all new columns will be `nan`s.