# pandas dataframe calculate rolling mean using cutomized window size

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy, rolling-computation

I'm trying to calculate the rolling mean/std for a column in dataframe. The pandas or numpy_ext rolling methods seem to need a fixed window size. The dataframe has a column "dates", I want to decide the window size based on the "dates", for example, when calculating mean/std, for rows at day 10, including rows from day 2 to day 6, for rows at day 11, including rows from day 3 to day 7, for rows at day 12, including rows from day 4 to day 8, etc.

I want to know if there are methods to do it except the brute force coding. Sample data, "quantity" is the target field to calculate mean and std.

| dates | material | location | quantity |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | C | A | 870 |
| 2 | D | A | 920 |
| 3 | C | A | 120 |
| 4 | D | A | 120 |
| 6 | C | A | 120 |
| 8 | D | A | 1200 |
| 8 | c | A | 720 |
| 10 | D | A | 480 |
| 11 | D | A | 600 |
| 12 | C | A | 720 |
| 13 | D | A | 80 |
| 13 | D | A | 600 |
| 14 | D | A | 1200 |
| 18 | E | B | 150 |

For example, for each row, I want to get the rolling mean for "quantity" of the previous 3-8 days (if any), the expected output will be:

```
| dates | material | location | quantity | Mean                    |
|-------|--------- |----------|----------|-------------------------|
| 1     | C        | A        | 870      | Nan                     |
| 2     | D        | A        | 920      | Nan                     |
| 3     | C        | A        | 120      | Nan                     |
| 4     | D        | A        | 120      | Nan                     |
| 6     | C        | A        | 120      |(870+920)/2 = 895        |
| 8     | D        | A        | 1200     |(870+920+120+120)/4=507.5|
| 8     | c        | A        | 720      |(870+920+120+120)/4=507.5|
| 10    | D        | A        | 480      |(920+120+120+120)/4=320  |
| 11    | D        | A        | 600      |(120+120+120)/3=120      |
| 12    | C        | A        | 720      |(120+120+1200+720)/4=540 |
| 13    | D        | A        | 80       |(120+1200+720)/3=680     |
| 13    | D        | A        | 600      |(120+1200+720)/3=680     |
| 14    | D        | A        | 1200     |(120+1200+720+480)/4=630 |
| 18    | E        | B       | 150|(480+600+720+80+600+1200)/6=613|
```

A follow-up question:

Is there a way to further filter the window by other columns? For example, when calculating the rolling mean for "quantity" of the previous 3-8 days, the rows in the rolling window must have the same "material" as the corresponding row. So the new expected output would be:

```
| dates | material | location | quantity | Mean                  |
|-------|--------- |----------|----------|-----------------------|
| 1     | C        | A        | 870      | Nan                   |
| 2     | D        | A        | 920      | Nan                   |
| 3     | C        | A        | 120      | Nan                   |
| 4     | D        | A        | 120      | Nan                   |
| 6     | C        | A        | 120      |(870)/1 = 870          |
| 8     | D        | A        | 1200     |(920+120)/2=520        |
| 8     | c        | A        | 720      |(870+120)/2=495        |
| 10    | D        | A        | 480      |(920+120)/2=520        |
| 11    | D        | A        | 600      |(120)/1 = 120          |
| 12    | C        | A        | 720      |(120+720)/2=420        |
| 13    | D        | A        | 80       |(1200)/1=1200          |
| 13    | D        | A        | 600      |(1200)/1=1200          |
| 14    | D        | A        | 1200     |(1200+480)/2=840       |
| 18    | E        | B        | 150      |Nan                    |
```

Comment: Can you provide the expected output and broken down computation for a few rows?

Comment: what do you mean by material?

Comment: "material" is the second column, so when dates = 6, material = C, so the window only contains row dates = 1, which also has material = C.

Comment: @zjsuper, added an answer for multiple columns

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inspired by @PaulS's answer, here is a simple way to select based on conditions from multiple columns:

```py
def get_selection(row):
    dates_mask = (df['dates'] < row['dates'] - 3) & (df['dates'] >= row['dates'] - 8)
    material_mask = df['material'] == row['material']
    return df[dates_mask & material_mask]

df['Mean'] = df.apply(lambda row: get_selection(row)['quantity'].mean(), 
                      axis=1)
df['Std'] = df.apply(lambda row: get_selection(row)['quantity'].std(), 
                     axis=1)
```

```
    dates material location  quantity    Mean         Std
0       1        C        A       870     NaN         NaN
1       2        D        A       920     NaN         NaN
2       3        C        A       120     NaN         NaN
3       4        D        A       120     NaN         NaN
4       6        C        A       120   870.0         NaN
5       8        D        A      1200   520.0  565.685425
6       8        C        A       720   495.0  530.330086
7      10        D        A       480   520.0  565.685425
8      11        D        A       600   120.0         NaN
9      12        C        A       720   420.0  424.264069
10     13        D        A        80  1200.0         NaN
11     13        D        A       600  1200.0         NaN
12     14        D        A      1200   840.0  509.116882
13     18        E        B       150     NaN         NaN
```

Answer (score 2):

You can perform your operation with a `rolling`, you however have to pre- and post-process the DataFrame a bit to generate the shift:

```
A = 3
B = 8
s = (df
  # de-duplicate by getting the sum/count per identical date
 .groupby('dates')['quantity']
 .agg(['sum', 'count'])
  # reindex to fill missing dates
 .reindex(range(df['dates'].min(),
                df['dates'].max()+1),
         fill_value=0)
  # compute classical rolling
 .rolling(B-A, min_periods=1).sum()
 # compute mean
 .assign(mean=lambda d: d['sum']/d['count'])
 ['mean'].shift(A+1)
 )

df['Mean'] = df['dates'].map(s)
```

output:

```
    dates material location  quantity        Mean
0       1        C        A       870         NaN
1       2        C        A       920         NaN
2       3        C        A       120         NaN
3       4        C        A       120         NaN
4       6        C        A       120  895.000000
5       8        D        A      1200  507.500000
6       8        D        A       720  507.500000
7      10        D        A       480  320.000000
8      11        D        A       600  120.000000
9      12        D        A       720  540.000000
10     13        D        A        80  680.000000
11     13        D        A       600  680.000000
12     14        D        A      1200  630.000000
13     18        E        B       150  613.333333
```

Comment: Nice workaround! (with de-duplicating, and filling the missing dates). However, this method is not very convenient for arbitrary aggregation functions (instead of mean) - for each one you need to think how to break it down into steps - and possible redo the algorithm multiple times. For example, for `std` here: you would have to calculate each mean first, then subtract it from each element individually (so you would have to start from the beginning again). For harder agg. functions there may be even more steps..

Comment: What if instead of doing `sum`, `count`, and all the other possible needed operations for the agg. functions, you just create 1 single column where collect all the selected values in a list. Then after collecting like so, you can perform any agg. function on each list. This will take only 1 calculation, and this will work with arbitrary agg. functions. But still, I think this would be a workaround of the proper `BaseIndexer` method.

Answer (score 2):

Another possible solution:

```
def f(x):
  return np.arange(np.amax([0, x-8]), np.amax([0, x-3]))

df['Mean'] = df.dates.map(lambda x:  df.quantity[df.dates.isin(f(x))].mean())
```

Output:

```
    dates material location  quantity        Mean
0       1        C        A       870         NaN
1       2        C        A       920         NaN
2       3        C        A       120         NaN
3       4        C        A       120         NaN
4       6        C        A       120  895.000000
5       8        D        A      1200  507.500000
6       8        D        A       720  507.500000
7      10        D        A       480  320.000000
8      11        D        A       600  120.000000
9      12        D        A       720  540.000000
10     13        D        A        80  680.000000
11     13        D        A       600  680.000000
12     14        D        A      1200  630.000000
13     18        E        B       150  613.333333
14     19        E        B      1416  640.000000
15     20        F        B      1164  650.000000
16     21        G        B     11520  626.666667
```

Answer (score 1):

The DataFrame constructor for anyone else to try:

```py
d = {'dates': [1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 8, 8, 10, 11, 12, 13, 13, 14, 18],
     'material': ['C','C','C','C','C','D','D','D','D','D','D','D','D','E'],
     'location':['A','A','A','A','A','A','A','A','A','A','A','A','A','B'],
     'quantity': [870, 920, 120, 120, 120, 1200, 720, 480, 600, 720, 80, 600, 1200, 150]}
df = pd.DataFrame(d)
```

---

[`df.rolling`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.rolling.html) **does** accept "a time period of each window. Each window will be a variable sized based on the observations included in the time-period. This is only valid for datetimelike indexes."

So we would have to convert your days to datetimelike (e.g., a `pd.Timestamp`, or a `pd.Timedelta`), and set it as index.

**But** this method won't have the ability perform the shift that you want (e.g., for day 14 you want not up to day 14 but up to day 10: 4 days before it).

---

So there is another option, which `df.rolling` also accepts:

#### Use a [`BaseIndexer`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.api.indexers.BaseIndexer.html) subclass

There is very little documentation on it and I'm not an expert, but I was able to hack my solution into it. Surely, there must be a better (proper) way to use all its attributes correctly, and hopefully someone will show it in their answer here.

**How I did it:**

Inside our `BaseIndexer` subclass, we have to define the [get_window_bounds](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/1.3.4/reference/api/pandas.api.indexers.BaseIndexer.get_window_bounds.html#pandas.api.indexers.BaseIndexer.get_window_bounds) method that returns a tuple of ndarrays: index positions of the starts of all windows, and those of the ends of all windows respectively (index positions like the ones that can be used in `iloc` - **not** with `loc`).

To to find them, I used the most efficient method from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73352590/14627505): [`np.searchsorted`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.searchsorted.html).

#### Your `'dates'` must be *sorted* for this.

Any keyword arguments that we pass to the `BaseIndexer` subclass constructor will be set as its attributes. I will set `day_from`, `day_to` and `days`:

```py
from pandas.api.indexers import BaseIndexer

class CustomWindow(BaseIndexer):    
    """
    Indexer that selects the dates.

    It uses the arguments:
    ----------------------
    day_from : int
    day_to : int
    days : np.ndarray
    """
    def get_window_bounds(self,
                          num_values: int, 
                          min_periods: int | None,
                          center: bool | None, 
                          closed: str | None) -> tuple[np.ndarray, np.ndarray]:
        """
        I'm not using these arguments, but they must be present (not sure why):
            `num_values` is the length of the df,
            `center`: False, `closed`: None.
        """
        days = self.days
        # With `side` I'm making both ends inclusive:
        window_starts = np.searchsorted(days, days + self.day_from, side='left')  
        window_ends =  np.searchsorted(days, days + self.day_to, side='right')
        return (window_starts, window_ends)
```

```py
# In my implementation both ends are inclusive:
day_from = -8
day_to = -4
days = df['dates'].to_numpy()

my_indexer = CustomWindow(day_from=day_from, day_to=day_to, days=days)
df[['mean', 'std']] = (df['quantity']
                       .rolling(my_indexer, min_periods=0)
                       .agg(['mean', 'std']))
```

Result:

```py
    dates material location  quantity        mean         std
0       1        C        A       870         NaN         NaN
1       2        C        A       920         NaN         NaN
2       3        C        A       120         NaN         NaN
3       4        C        A       120         NaN         NaN
4       6        C        A       120  895.000000   35.355339
5       8        D        A      1200  507.500000  447.911822
6       8        D        A       720  507.500000  447.911822
7      10        D        A       480  320.000000  400.000000
8      11        D        A       600  120.000000    0.000011
9      12        D        A       720  540.000000  523.067873
10     13        D        A        80  680.000000  541.109970
11     13        D        A       600  680.000000  541.109970
12     14        D        A      1200  630.000000  452.990066
13     18        E        B       150  613.333333  362.803896
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I have another follow-up question, for BaseIndexer it finds the bounds for each window, is it possible to further filter the windows? For example, when calculating the mean of dates "6", I want the row in the windows should also have the same "material" as dates "6", in this case, the expected mean of dates "6" should be 870/1 = 870. @Vladimir Fokow

Comment: @zjsuper, I am sorry - I don't quite understand what you're asking. What is "dates 6" - do you mean the row where the 'dates' is 6? And why would it be 870? Can you give more examples?

Comment: Hi, I update the follow up question in the main post, thanks. @Vladimir Fokow